# "int cannot be dereferenced" error

Tags: integer, int, gettext, parseint

When answering, you kept the programming slang to a minimum. I keep receiving the same error:

```
int cannot be dereferenced
```

I have a text field where the user inputs an integer and what I'm trying to do is receive that input and store it in a variable. The text field's variable is `pricePay`. I could give more information if needed, am I putting this line of code in the wrong place? am I missing something?

```
private void pricePayActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    int pricePay = Integer.parseInt(pricePay.getText());
}
```

Comment: you are calling a local variable (`int pricePay`) with the same name of the text field `pricePay`. That line is ok per-se, but in following lines you will be acting on the integer, not on the text field.

Answer (score 2):

When you write

```
int pricePay = Integer.parseInt(pricePay.getText());
                                ↑
                             an int
```

Then `pricePay` becomes an `int`, it'll hide the *data member* `pricePay`.

Since `int` is primitive, it doesn't have any methods, including `getText()`, hence the error `"int cannot be dereferenced"`. You can do:

```
int pricePay = Integer.parseInt(this.pricePay.getText());
                                ↑
```

Or (better) change the name of the variable you're declaring in the method.